# Laravel valet Request::ip();

Tags: laravel, request, ip, laravel-valet

I'm using Valet for my local development in mac and when i try to do Request::ip(); for get the ip of visits, I keep getting 127.0.0.1, I try to using this package antonioribeiro/tracker but also does't work,
I know that what i'm getting is the ipv4 and what i want is the ipv6 but
I want to get the public address. Maybe is because valet?, because when i change the domain in valet .dev to .localhost I get 1:: Please, can someone help me, thanks.

Comment: Google the differences between external and local ip addresses.

Comment: did you figure it out?